# How can i separate a specific tag in java

Tags: java, android, html, tags, jsoup

I have this html:

```
<p dir="ltr">Hello<br>
<img src="/path"> <br>
<b>hey</b> <b>hello</b> fox<br>
cat</p>
```

how can i separate the `img` tag from `p`?
I want it to be like this:

```
<p dir="ltr">Hello<br>
<br>
<b>hey</b> <b>hello</b> fox<br>cat</p>
<img src="/path">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexOf('<img'), you will get the Start index

Then use indexOf('>'), you will get the index of End tag

Suppose you have the string like

```
String html = "<p dir="ltr">Hello<br><img src="path"> <br><b>hey</b> <b>hello</b> fox<br>cat</p>";
String image = html.substring(html.indexOf("<img"), html.indexOf(">"));
```

Then you know what to do!!

Inform me if you need anything else

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    div.append(img[0]);
    img.remove;
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="div">
    <p dir="ltr">Hello<br>
    <img src="" alt="path"></img>
    <b>hey</b> <b>hello</b> fox<br>
    cat
    </p>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```